# How to add Auto Increment Id in MySQL table based on sorted sequence of another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, auto-increment

I have a table where I want to add auto Incrementing Id which isn't there. The rows aren't sorted. I want to add ID column based on the lexicographical order of another column, As shown below:

```
CURRENT TABLE            AFTER ADDING ID

CLASS | ITEM           ID | CLASS | ITEM
------|-------         ---|-------|-------
fruits| banana          1 | fruits| apple
------|--------        ---|-------|-------
tools | hammer          2 | fruits| banana
------|--------        ---|-------|-------
fruits| apple           3 | flura | banyan
------|--------        ---|-------|-------
flura | banyan          4 | tools | hammer
------|--------        ---|-------|-------
fauna | human           5 | fauna | human
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Auto-Increment ID to existing table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753321/add-auto-increment-id-to-existing-table)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use a programming language (Python is awesome for these kinds of use cases and I'll use that in my answer). The steps required would be as follows:

1. Create a temp table in your database with the auto-increment field
2. Query your database in Python and retrieve all rows
3. Sort the list based on your desired field
4. Insert the sorted data into the temp table
5. Rename the current table to another name
6. Rename temp to the current table

Comment: Yeah. I eventually did that. But was looking for some native way to do that.

Comment: Steps 2,3,4 are simply the single SQL: `INSERT INTO temp SELECT ... ORDER BY ...;`

Comment: @RickJames Yeah you're right. I was thinking of the most general way to do the sorting but for this use case this query totally works without the need of programming.

Comment: There's the old addage "If you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail."  Your hammer is Python; mine is SQL.

Answer (score 1):

1. Alter Table to add ID column

> ```
> ALTER TABLE
>       `your_table`
>     ADD
>       COLUMN `ID` INT NULL auto_increment;
> ```

2. Update your table

```
     UPDATE your_table  SET
        your_table.ID = a.ID, 
        your_table.CLASS = a.CLASS,
         your_table.ITEM = a.ITEM, FROM (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CLASS ASC) AS ID, CLASS, ITEM 
        FROM your_table) AS a WHERE 
        a.CLASS = your_table.CLASS
        a.CLASS = your_table.ITEM
```